# Node: Client side angular service or server side object?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, client-server, mean-stack

I am creating a rating web app, much like yelp, which allows people to rate places and also see the average rating of a place. My database holds all of these ratings, but I want the average rating to be calculated at a later time, when the customer actually looks up the location.

Where should the calculation of the average ratings take place? Should these calculations be completed client side, as an angular service? Or should these be completed on the server, through methods saved on a JavaScript object? Or something else entirely?

Everything is built in MEAN stack. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
The average rating is for display only, and is not immediately recalculated based on some client event. It is averaging in the single digits, from no more than one hundred rows.

Comment: Possibly do business login processing on server side.Client side should used with minmun data processing

Comment: Is the average rating only for display or is it recalculated based on some client event?  How much data is required to complete the calculation?  Is it averaging values from hundreds, thousands, or more rows?

Comment: @jbrown thanks for the questions, I have included answers in the edit above.

Comment: @ToriHuang - I would do the calculation server side since you don't need to recalculate.  Otherwise, if there was a need to recalculate based on a client event and for such a small amount of data, then I would do the calculation client side to limit round trips to the server.

Comment: I agree with you @jbrown, thank you :) could you put that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the calculation server side since you don't need to recalculate. Otherwise, if there was a need to recalculate based on a client event and for such a small amount of data, then I would do the calculation client side to limit round trips to the server